# Setting a variable in XML document from Word Add-in C# code

Tags: c#, xml, word-addins

I am using log4net in a Word add-in to create log files. The add-in will be deployed to multiple users so the folder path found in the App.config file will need to change for each user.
In the add-in initialization I call a function that gets the User Profile folder and sets that as a variable (I believe) for the app.config file.

```
public void GetCurrentUser()
        {
            string user = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
            log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["UserFolder"] = user;
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }
```

and my app.config xml file looks like this:

```
<log4net debug="true">
      <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%Property{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\logfile.txt" /> 
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
...
```

but it is not writing to the log when I run the add-in. Can someone please point me in the right direction?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your xml (not in c#), try replacing `user` with `UserFolder`.

```xml
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%Property{UserFolder}\AppData\Local\Temp\logfile.txt" />
```

In your code, you are setting a property called UserFolder but your xml contains no such reference.